# ImportError :No module named RPI.GPIO

Tags: python, gpio

I use Raspberry pi3 model B, I have installed RPI.GPIO successfully with both code (pip install, sudo apt-get install) that you see bellow, but when I tried `import RPI.GPIO` it says:

```
ImportError: No module named RPI.GPIO
```

What should I do?

Thank you in advance for your help.

[The code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mg4jd.jpg)

Comment: `RPi` not `RPI`

Answer (score 2):

Try `import RPi.GPIO`. it's small letter `i`. source https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/BasicUsage/

Comment: Thans alot for answering my question, but my code doesn't work with small letter i ,error :no module name RPi